# Can't remove steam

Tags: 14.04, unity, apt, launcher, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install steam from the .deb from the steam website (steam_latest.deb) and this didn't work; I installed later with apt-get install steam (along with the 32 libraries and stuff) and this was successful, but I was left with a huge steam-launcher icon in the unity launcher, that does nothing and says "Invalid UTF-8" as a description, presumably from the first attempt, which was done with the deb through software center. I tried apt-get remove steam, but just got rid of the one that actually worked. Great. Tried to reinstall from deb, and uninstall again, now I have 3 giant ugly useless icons, and no working steam. Wonderful. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  **;-)** For the future, please read [How to install software on Ubuntu if you're a Windows User](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)

Comment: @cosmoflop12 if this has solved your problem please let us know.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what solved it, but I think the purge ended up doing it. But it took a reboot before the icons went away. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @cosmoflop12 Great that this solved the problem, please close the question by marking the answer, i.e., which ever solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing this `sudo apt-get purge steam-launcher` and then install steam again.

**purge** - Purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged. Purge meaning that any configuration files are deleted too.
Let me know if this works or not.

Also try this and see which all directories have steam installed in it `dpkg -L steam-launcher`
Make sure you have run all this before `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of these thing you need to use `autoremove` instead of `remove` so it will be like this

```
sudo apt-get autoremove steam-launcher
```

After you remove Steam, you can easily install it back on ur system with the `.deb` file downloaded from steam official website.
Regards